# jquery form - two buttons - one to use ajax, one not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I want to use jquery for validation of the form before I submit. If I click on one of the buttons, I have it save the data via an ajax call. For the other button I want to submit the form, but not have it go through ajax, just do a submit the old fashioned way and go to that page.

I had the submitHandler in my validate() function, which works great for doing the ajax stuff, but what about for the other button where I don't want to use ajax? Do I remove the submitHandler portion from the validate() function? If so, then how should I set up for using ajax? Do I put it in the event handler for the click on that button? If so, how should I set it up?

Comment: To clarify, I have no problem determining which button was pressed. I have click event handlers for each one, and that part works just fine. The problem lies in setting up the call to ajax. If I put it in the submitHandler part of the validate() function, then the ajax is always called. So I tried just putting the $.ajax() call in the function which handles the event for button 1, which I want to just call ajax and return. If I do this, then the form get submitted the old fashioned way, instead of using ajax. I also tried to call it via $('#form').ajax(), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create 2 different functions or just one parameterized with a boolean to indicate whether to send ajax request or just submit the form? the latter may be done using the JQuery submit function.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. I just need to know how to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to bind a personal event

```
$('form').on('submitajax submit', function(e){
    if(e.type === 'submitajax'){
        //ajaxstuff
    }
    else{
        //classic stuff
    }
})
```

And your *ajax button* will trigger the *submitajax* event

Answer (score 0):

Your validation function can be like this:

```
function bar( ajax )
{
  var valid = true, fooForm = $('#fooForm');
  // do validation stuff

  if( !valid ) return;

  if( ajax ){
   $.post(fooForm.attr('action'), fooForm.serialize());
  }else{
   fooForm.submit();
  }
}
```

And your buttons:

```
<input type="button" value="With Ajax" onclick="bar( true )" />
<input type="button" value="Old Fashion" onclick="bar( false )" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check JavaScript events on submitting form.
Just consider form:

```
<form class="js-form">
  <a class="js-save">Save</a>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


$('.js-from').on('click', function(event){
   if (event.target === event.currentTarget){
     # Triggers on click submit input that triggers as part of form and target same
     # Call ajax stuff
   } else {
     # Triggers on click link witch is fired as click as not a part of form
     # Call other ajax or link stuff
   }
});
```

One function for cheching if form submit on submit button or link that can do any thing other

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my ajax button click event handlers, I needed to add
    event.preventDefault();
Then I could add the $.ajax() call to the one where I wanted to call ajax, and to the other one just did the submit normally.

Thank you for all of your responses, it was an interesting exercise and I learned a bit more about the intricacies of this type of coding.